# CreateView and UpdateView based on type of submission?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have 2 models in Django that are connected by a one to one relationship. For example:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    username    = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    email       = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,
                                       null=True)
    bio            = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    avatar         = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    profile        = models.OneToOneField(Settings, null=True)


class Profile(models.Model):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
    )

    bio     = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    avatar  = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    gender  = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, null=True)
    dob     = models.DateField(max_length=8, null=True)
```

Every user may have `Profile` details, but some users may not have entered any information so they might not have any details provided yet (0 rows). What I'd like to do is create a settings page that either creates or updates the user profile details upon submission. Basically this is what I have so far:

```
class ProfileSettings(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'oauth/profile-settings.html'
    form_class = ProfileForm
    model = Profile

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return get_object_or_404(Profile, user=self.request.user)
```

With this type of view, the update works when a user has profile details, but when the user doesn't have profile details a 404 error is displayed instead. Is it possible to display the view to the user even though he doesn't have profile details and if so, could they create profile details for themselves and then can go back and update them?

Comment: did you mean: profile        = models.OneToOneField(Profile, null=True) ?

Comment: @DmitriiG. Hmm, what is the difference?

Comment: @DmitriiG. Is there a difference?